# What is the remainder of $1!+2!+...+ (10^{10})! \mod40$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I want to know if my thinking is correct about this question!

The question:  $1!+2!+...+ (10^{10})! \mod40$?

How 
\begin{align}
1 \equiv 1 \mod40\\
2 \equiv 2 \mod40\\
3 \equiv 3 \mod40\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
(40-1)\equiv (40-1) \mod40
\end{align}
Then, If  we  multiplying term by term we have that: $3! \equiv 3! \mod40$, for example. On this, I can write $(10^{10})! \equiv (10^{10})! \mod40$.

So, $1!+2!+...+ (10^{10})! \equiv 1!+2!+...+ (10^{10})! \mod40$ and my answer is that remainder is: $1!+2!+...+ (10^{10})!$

Will be correct or is other thinking?

Comment: Your answer can't possibly be right, as the remainder mod $40$ has to be a number in the set $\{0, 1, \dots 39 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now after all help, I get it! So, the answer is:

$1! + 2! +3!+ 4!+ 5!+...+ (10^{10})! \mod40$, how for the numbers bigger than 5 are multiples of 40, we have that $5!+...+ (10^{10})! \equiv 0\mod40$ and

\begin{align}
1! \equiv 1 \mod 40\\
2! \equiv 2 \mod 40\\
3! \equiv 6 \mod 40\\
4! \equiv 24 \mod 40
\end{align}

then, $1!+2!+3!+4! \equiv33 \mod40$ and the remainder is: 33.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $n \geq 5$ has $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{40}$.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer.